# Power BI - measure not impacting visual properly

Tags: powerbi

I have a measure like this:

```
Sum of ABC = 
CALCULATE([Sum of ABC],'table'[nr] IN { "R" })
```

the measure works fine, sums column ABC for values where NR = 'R'. I have this measure setup in a table, when I click on a value on this table, I expect it to filter to entries which only have a value of 'R' - however, it does not seem to do that. Is there something I can do to do this? i.e. when I press a value of the measure, it should just filter all other visuals to where NR = 'R'